# FileNotFoundException при обращении к методу api, хотя метод есть

Tags: java, android

Возникает такая проблема: есть метод у api и при обращении к нему на некоторых устройствах всё работает хорошо, а на других возникает ошибка FileNotFoundException. Т.е. при одном и том же запросе на разных устройствах разный  результат. В чём может быть проблема? 
Код потока:

```
protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
        try {
            switch (strings[0]){
                case "login":
                    URL_API+="/login";
                    break;
                case "forget-password":
                    URL_API+="/forget-password";
                    break;
                case "registration":
                    URL_API+="/registration";
                    break;
                case "my-cars-page":
                    URL_API+="/my-cars-page";
                    break;
                case "history-page":
                    URL_API+="/history-page?"+strings[2];
                    break;
                case "get-services":
                    URL_API+="/get-services";
                    break;
                case "get-services2":
                    URL_API+="/get-services?carWashId="+strings[2];
                    break;
                case "get-add-services":
                    URL_API+="/get-add-services";
                    break;
                case "get-add-services2":
                    URL_API+="/get-add-services?carWashId="+strings[2];
                    break;
                case "get-time-and-price":
                    URL_API+="/get-time-and-price?services="+strings[2];
                    break;
                case "get-select-map-periods":
                    URL_API+="/get-select-map-periods?"+strings[2];
                    break;
                case "get-avaible-times":
                    URL_API+="/get-available-times?"+strings[2];
                    break;
                case "get-car-washes-by-filter":
                    URL_API+="/get-car-washes-by-filter?"+strings[2];
                    break;
                case "signup-car-wash":
                    URL_API+="/signup-car-wash";
                    break;
                case "carwash-contacts-page":
                    URL_API+="/carwash-contacts-page?"+strings[2];
                    break;
                case "carwash-contacts-page2":
                    URL_API+="/carwash-contacts-page";
                    break;
                case "chat-inbox-page":
                    URL_API+="/chat-inbox-page";
                    break;
                case "remove-transport":
                    URL_API+="/remove-transport";
                    break;
                case "add-transport":
                    URL_API+="/add-transport";
                    break;
                case "change-transport":
                    URL_API+="/change-transport";
                    break;
                case "carwash-sales-page":
                    URL_API+="/carwash-sales-page?"+strings[2];
                    break;
                case "is-free":
                    URL_API+="/is-free";
                    break;
                case "carwash-comfort-page":
                    URL_API+="/carwash-comfort-page?"+strings[2];
                    break;
                case "get-available-dates":
                    URL_API+="/get-available-dates?carWashId="+strings[2];
                    break;
                case "change-settings":
                    URL_API+="/change-settings";
                    break;
                case "get-signed-record":
                    URL_API+="/get-signed-record";
                    break;
                case "cancel-record":
                    URL_API+="/cancel-record";
                    break;
                case "complete-record":
                    URL_API+="/complete-record";
                    break;
                case "about-car-wash":
                    URL_API+="/about-car-wash?"+strings[2];
                    break;
                case "advert-viewed":
                    URL_API+="/advert-viewed";
                    break;
                case "get-mailing":
                    URL_API+="/get-mailing";
                    break;
                case "email-exist":
                    URL_API+="/email-exist";
                    break;
            }
            URL url = new URL(URL_API);
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            conn.setDoOutput(true);
            conn.setDoInput(true);
            conn.setConnectTimeout (500000);
            conn.setReadTimeout (500000);
            if((strings[0].equals("my-cars-page"))||(strings[0].equals("get-signed-record"))||(strings[0].equals("history-page"))||(strings[0].equals("get-services2"))||(strings[0].equals("get-add-services2"))||(strings[0].equals("get-time-and-price"))||(strings[0].equals("get-select-map-periods"))||(strings[0].equals("get-avaible-times"))||(strings[0].equals("get-car-washes-by-filter"))||(strings[0].equals("carwash-contacts-page2"))||(strings[0].equals("chat-inbox-page"))||(strings[0].equals("is-free"))||(strings[0].equals("carwash-contacts-page"))||(strings[0].equals("carwash-sales-page"))||(strings[0].equals("carwash-comfort-page"))||(strings[0].equals("get-available-dates"))||(strings[0].equals("about-car-wash"))||(strings[0].equals("get-mailing"))){

                conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
                conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Bearer " + strings[1]);
                conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", "" );
            }else {
                if((strings[0].equals("get-services"))||(strings[0].equals("get-add-services"))||(strings[0].equals("signup-car-wash"))||(strings[0].equals("remove-transport"))||(strings[0].equals("add-transport"))||(strings[0].equals("change-transport"))||(strings[0].equals("change-settings"))||(strings[0].equals("cancel-record"))||(strings[0].equals("complete-record"))||(strings[0].equals("advert-viewed"))){
                    conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Bearer " + strings[1]);
                    conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", "" + Integer.toString(strings[2].getBytes().length));
                }else {
                    conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", "" + Integer.toString(strings[1].getBytes().length));
                }
            }
            OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
            if((strings[0].equals("get-services"))||(strings[0].equals("get-add-services"))||(strings[0].equals("signup-car-wash"))||(strings[0].equals("remove-transport"))||(strings[0].equals("add-transport"))||(strings[0].equals("change-transport"))||(strings[0].equals("change-settings"))||(strings[0].equals("cancel-record"))||(strings[0].equals("complete-record"))||(strings[0].equals("advert-viewed"))){
                data = strings[2].getBytes("UTF-8");
            }else {
                data = strings[1].getBytes("UTF-8");
            }
            os.write(data);
            data = null;
            conn.connect();
            int responseCode= conn.getResponseCode();
            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            if(strings[0].equals("get-signed-record")) {
                Log.i("MyLog","get-signed-record");
            }
            is =  new BufferedInputStream(conn.getInputStream());//Ошибка возникает здесь
            byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
            int bytesRead;
            while ((bytesRead = is.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                baos.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
            }
            data = baos.toByteArray();
            resultString = new String(data, "UTF-8");
            return resultString;
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }
```

Log:

```
02-07 13:39:01.029 24399-24556/com.project.avtomoy W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: https://www.avtomoy.online/api/get-car-washes-by-filter?approximateTime=30.0&timeInterval=00:30 - 02:30
02-07 13:39:01.030 24399-24556/com.project.avtomoy W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:206)
02-07 13:39:01.030 24399-24556/com.project.avtomoy W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.getInputStream(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:210)
02-07 13:39:01.030 24399-24556/com.project.avtomoy W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:25)
02-07 13:39:01.030 24399-24556/com.project.avtomoy W/System.err:     at com.project.avtomoy.ThreadRequest.doInBackground(ThreadRequest.java:176)
02-07 13:39:01.031 24399-24556/com.project.avtomoy W/System.err:     at com.project.avtomoy.ThreadRequest.doInBackground(ThreadRequest.java:18)
02-07 13:39:01.031 24399-24556/com.project.avtomoy W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:292)
02-07 13:39:01.031 24399-24556/com.project.avtomoy W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
02-07 13:39:01.031 24399-24556/com.project.avtomoy W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
02-07 13:39:01.032 24399-24556/com.project.avtomoy W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
02-07 13:39:01.032 24399-24556/com.project.avtomoy W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
02-07 13:39:01.032 24399-24556/com.project.avtomoy W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Comment: `responseCode` проверяйте, там явно 404 вам прилетает.

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja, это я понимаю что прилетает 404, но мне хотелось бы узнать почему на разных устройствах разный результат

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja, я сейчас проверил responseCode и там 400 ошибка

Comment: `&timeInterval=00:30 - 02:30` - подозреваю, что проблема в этих пробелах. Попробуйте закодировать строку запроса: `URL url = new URL(URLEncoder.encode(URL_API, "utf-8"));`

Comment: @woesss, не помогло, везде падает с исключением MalformedURLException

Comment: Попробуйте просто убрать пробелы, например так: `URL url = new URL(URL_API.replace(" ", "");` Сомневаюсь, что они там вообще нужны.

Comment: @woesss, спасибо, помогло. Только странно почему на некоторых устройствах всё нормально, а на каких то выдавало ошибку?

Comment: Разная имплементация `HttpURLConnection` в разных версиях Андроид, в этом будет ответ. В вашем коде если прилетает ответ 4хх, нет смысла пытаться читать поток с ответом.